# Need to use a UMAX Astra 4100 USB Scanner

Tags: scanner

I a newbie to linux. I cant seem to use my usb scanner which is a UMAX Astra 4100 model. The scanner wont detect.

I poked around a lot on the net and ran this command in terminal

```
sudo sane-find-scanner
```

I got the following message

```
found USB scanner (vendor=0x0461 [Primax], product=0x038c [USB Scanner], chip=GL646_HP) at libusb:003:007
```

I dont know how to proceed from here.
Please help.

Comment: I'm trying to connect this usb scanner to a ubuntu 11.10  operating system.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately your particular scanner is not supported by your Vendor to run on linux.

Looking at the [SANE compatibility lists](http://www.sane-project.org/sane-mfgs.html#Z-UMAX) - it is also marked as unsupported by the opensource SANE community.

For your next scanner purchase you should consult the SANE website for linux compatibility if the Vendor themselves say they do not have a linux driver.